# How to handle error in golang when we call a route with value from DB (/user/{user_id} ) How can I handle error if user_id used is not in DB

Tags: mysql, database, go, error-handling, backend

[Golang code where API call for getting user details from db using user_id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PjZA.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the err after your SQL SELECT statement for an error of type `sql.ErrNoRows`, e.g.

```golang
if err != nil {
   if err == sql.ErrNoRows {
       fmt.Fprintf(w, "User ID not found in DB") 
     } else { 
       fmt.Fprintf(w, "Handle others possible DB errors")
     } 
}
```